# in Python 3, how to create a number-like object?

Tags: python

I want to store a number (`int`, `float`, etc.) and it's scientific notation (including it's precision) into one object.

For example, I have `a = 0.001` as it's value and `1.0e-3` as it's scientific notation. Currently I have a class:

```
def numLike():
    def __init__(self, n, p):
        self.n = n
        self.p = p

a = numLike(0.001, '1.0e-3')
```

So that I can at least relate these two values into 1 object. And when I want to do the calculations, I'll use `a.n`, and when print them out use `a.p`.

What I want to achieve is that Python recognize `a` as `a.n` when doing caculation, and `a` as `a.p` when no calculation is involved. So when I input `a + 0.003`, it should give me `0.004`, and when I input `a` it returns `'1.0e-3'` automatically.

Comment: In your code you are defining a function numLike not a class. Is it a typo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to store the string representation, just generate it when needed: extend `float` and override `__str__`:

```
class x(float):
    def __str__(self):
        return "{:e}".format(self)

print (float(101))  # 101.0
print (x(101))      # 1.010000e+02
```

or, to pass the precision along,

```
class x(float):
    def __new__(cls, value, prec=6):
        self = float.__new__(cls, value)
        self.prec = prec
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        return "{:.{}e}".format(self, self.prec)

print (float(101))  # 101.0
print (x(101))      # 1.010000e+02
print (x(101, 2))   # 1.01e+02
```

If you decide to go your way, you'll have to override all arithmetics (`__add__` and friends) and delegate it to `self.n`.